# How to secure Lexik Translation Bundle routes?

Tags: symfony, security, translation, symfony-2.8

I am using Symfony 2.8 and I import my translations into the database with the help of the [Lexik translation bundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle) - this allows me to have a route like /admin/translations where i can see statistics and add more translations (well, the customer will).

**The problem** is that this route has no security at all. I can just access it without even being logged in. I have an annotation that makes sure you have a certain role in order to access the given route.

**My question** is how can I add my custom annotation to the lexik controller that renders the translation templates (like overview and grid pages) without actually writing code inside the bundle (vendor folder). Is there a way to add it in the config?

Comment: how do you actually handle the security? which kind of annotations do you use?

Comment: For example, if I need this route (or all routes in a class) to be visible only to the administrator I use 
@RequiresRole({"Administrator"})
This is a custom annotation. Administrator is also a custom role, it is not registered in symfony config or anything. That is why I put my question to be: how can I add my custom annotation to the translation routes of the lexik bundle without editing their code directly.

Comment: You should implement a leader of Yaml type ad example so you can configure outside the code

Answer (score 1):

In your security.yml you just need to add access control on the admin path

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I don't use this method of restricting users, I don't have a config defining the roles. The roles are defined in my database and I already have an annotation that I use in all my controllers. I want to add the same annotation to the lexik controller.